# How do I get publish_actions permission with Facebook

Tags: facebook

I follow a tutor for connection with Facebook which uses the following code to connect to Facebook successfully.

The code follows -

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    // TODO: Handle the access token

                    // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                    // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                    form.setAttribute("action", 'loadMainPage.ashx');

                    var field = document.createElement("input");
                    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                    field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                    form.appendChild(field);

                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                }
            });

        };
```

How can I ask for publish_actions permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform are you using?  See [Facebook's official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/).

An excerpt:

> **Requesting permissions**
>
> Each type of login flow has its own method of requesting these permissions:
>
> - Web login with the JavaScript SDK uses a scope option with the FB.login function call.
> - Other types of web login should add the scope parameter to the Login
>   dialog URL that they redirect to.
> - Android login uses the setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions
>   on the LoginButton class.
> - iOS login uses the readPermissions and publishPermissions properties
>   in the FBLoginView class.